# Short battery life of the laptop from ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, laptop, asus, battery

In July this year I bought the Asus VivoBook Pro 15 laptop. I installed the Ubuntu 18.04 linux operating system.
My problem is that the battery life is only 1.5 hours, while the reviews and specifications state that it can be even 6-8 hours.

Does anyone have similar?
Is this a common problem with Ubuntu?
Is there a package that can optimize your computer's battery life?

Answer (score 6):

It is a known effect. You can install TLP.

Open a Terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

For setting the TLP you can use the command line or an GUI. For the GUI you need to install TLPUI

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps
sudo apt install tlpui
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have a question whether installing tlp and its default settings are enough to solve the problem with short battery life?
I am asking because I installed the tlp and disconnected the power cable, the battery life improved by a few minutes (I did not work on the battery all the time, reading from the battery indicator in the upper right corner).
I also read about the laptop-mode-tools package - any opinions about it?

Comment: I know its some time but what did the trick for me was changing the video to the internal GPU, it gave me double the battery but still something about 3h or less.